# SQL update table depending on another table

Tags: sql, sql-update, case

I have two tables and one (`tb1`) has columns date, breakfast, lunch, dinner, day of week. The other (`tb2`) has an arrival date and a departure date.

I'm looking to update the catering numbers by the number of rows in `tb2` that meet the criteria `tb1.date is between tb2.arrivaldate and tb2.departuredate`.

What complicates things further is breakfast and dinner only get updated if `tb2.dayofweek` is a weekday and breakfast and lunch get updated if the day of week is at the weekend. Both tables are temp tables if that matters. Any help would be appreciated!

Here are my results:

[image]

Comment: Please show data and expected results in table form

Comment: Show your code.  We need to see what you have try already

Answer (score 0):

You haven't mentioned what flavour of SQL you're working with, and as a couple of the comments already note no table & data scripts or what you've tried so far. This isn't going to be your final code then, but it should give you an idea of one approach that could be used to get the numbers you want.

```
select
    tb1.date, 
    count(tb2.arrivaldate) as breakfast, 
    sum(case when tb1.day_of_week in ('Saturday', 'Sunday') then 1 else 0 end) as lunch, 
    sum(case when tb1.day_of_week not in ('Saturday', 'Sunday') then 1 else 0 end) as dinner
from
    tb1 left join tb2 on tb1.date between tb2.arrivaldate and tb2.departuredate
group by tb1.date
```

Note this is off the top of my head, I haven't tried it or tested it with your data ;)